# Multiple D3 Graphs, Two Axis', No Category's

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, graph

I am working with dimple js and trying to get two object variables to use the same axis while graphing. I have provided and example data set, it does not include category's, simply the name of the test (x axis) and two values that need to be graphed separately. I am considering a very hackish solution of duplicating all the data and adding separate category's to each set. If you have a cleaner solution I would really appreciate it.

**Test Data**

```
var data=[
   {name:"test 1",firstAccuracy:33,accuracy:50},
   {name:"test 2",firstAccuracy:38,accuracy:60},
   {name:"test 3",firstAccuracy:45,accuracy:50},
   {name:"test 4",firstAccuracy:55,accuracy:80},
   {name:"test 5",firstAccuracy:52,accuracy:72},
   {name:"test 6",firstAccuracy:60,accuracy:70},
   {name:"test 7",firstAccuracy:54,accuracy:82},
   {name:"test 8",firstAccuracy:60,accuracy:60},
   {name:"test 9",firstAccuracy:70,accuracy:85}
]
```

**Relevant Javascript**

```
function drawGraph(){
    var svg = dimple.newSvg("#chartContainer", 590, 400);
    var myChart = new dimple.chart(svg, data);
    myChart.setBounds(60, 30, 505, 305);
    var x = myChart.addCategoryAxis("x", "name");
    var y1 = myChart.addMeasureAxis("y", "accuracy");
    var y2 = myChart.addMeasureAxis("y", "firstAccuracy");
    var s1 = myChart.addSeries("Result Accuracy", dimple.plot.line,[x,y1]);
    var s2 = myChart.addSeries("First Result Accuracy", dimple.plot.line,[x,y2]);
    myChart.draw();

}
```

**What it currently looks like**

[image]

**What I'm Aiming for**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think the real answer is to have data contain two sets for result and firstResult with a  series parameter to tell them apart, somewhat like in this example.
http://dimplejs.org/examples_viewer.html?id=lines_horizontal_stacked

However if reformatting the `data` object is out of the question you can do the following:

```
var svg = dimple.newSvg("#chartContainer", 590, 400);
var myChart = new dimple.chart(svg, data);
myChart.setBounds(60, 30, 505, 305);
var x = myChart.addCategoryAxis("x", "name");
var y1 = myChart.addMeasureAxis("y", "accuracy");
y2 = Object.create(y1);
y2.measure = "firstAccuracy";
var s1 = myChart.addSeries("Result Accuracy", dimple.plot.line,[x,y1]);
var s2 = myChart.addSeries("First Result Accuracy", dimple.plot.line,[x,y2]);

myChart.draw();
```

This works for me in FireFox, although I think that using Object.create like this is pretty messy.